# Service Endpoint IP Filtering and vnet rules

Tags: azureservicebus

I have followed the instructions to add a service endpoint to the vnet my k8s cluster is running in and applied it as a vnet rule to my service bus. This has as expected stopped any calls the originate outside of the cluster vnet. For development I need to be able to connect to the service bus from my local machine as well, we will also need to specify a range of IP to allow access via Express route from our on prem solutions. No matter how I configure the ip filtering it is blocked. I have even configured a 0.0.0.0/0 Access filter and still get denied. The documentation implies that you can use vnet rules and ip filters together, is this not the case? or am I doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot use them together. VNet will block all traffic that is not on the VNet and takes precedence over IP Filter.

Comment: Just seems odd that they have this text on the screen in the azure portal "Configure network security for your Service Bus Namespace using Virtual Networks and/or IP Filters." Sort of implies that you can use both